# PHP Regex to extract values in string

Tags: php, regex

https://regex101.com/r/xTu3Zo/1/

I have the following regex:

`\[([^]]+)]`

And the following string:

```
Je naam (verplicht) [text* your-test] Je e-mailadres (verplicht) [email* your-tester] Onderwerp [text your-testerer] Je bericht [textarea your-testererer] [area-without-attribute] 1
```

I want to extract everything inbetween the brackets (for example "your-test") without "text*".

Desired output:

```
your-test 
your-tester 
your-testerer 
your-testererer 
area-without-attribute
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\[(?:\w+\*?\s+)?([^][]+)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fOU0BK/4). Details:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?:\w+\*?\s+)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `\*?` - an optional asterisk
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `([^][]+)` - Group 1: any 1 or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/YqmZv):

```
$text = "Je naam (verplicht) [text* your-test] Je e-mailadres (verplicht) [email* your-tester] Onderwerp [text your-testerer] Je bericht [textarea your-testererer] [area-without-attribute]";
if (preg_match_all('~\[(?:\w+\*?\s+)?([^][]+)]~', $text, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => your-test
    [1] => your-tester
    [2] => your-testerer
    [3] => your-testererer
    [4] => area-without-attribute
)
```